# Unwanted line break in source code with php include

Tags: bash, php

I am using this script to generate a regular-changing email address with `qmail`

```
#!/bin/bash

##### change these settings #####

qmailpath="/your/path/to/.qmail-"
wwwpath="/your/path/to/html/tempmail"
host="@my.host"
prefix="temp-"
length="16"

##### do not change the following #####

oldmail="$qmailpath"$(cat "$wwwpath" | cut -d@ -f1)
newmail="$prefix"$(date +%s%N | md5sum | cut -c 1-"$length")

rm "$oldmail"
touch "$qmailpath$newmail"
echo -n "$newmail$host" > "$wwwpath"
```

I am using this php command to include the email address in my webpage:

```
<a href="mailto:<?php include('tempmail');?>"><?php include('tempmail');?></a>
```

It works fine, but if I take a look at the source code of the webpage, I recognize a strange line break:

```
<a href="mailto:temp-rpwaa44hff5kch8smfuv3@myhost
">temp-rpwaa44hff5kch8smfuv3@myhost
</a>
```

Where does this come from and how can I remove it?

**UPDATE**: I updated the script and added `-n` after `echo`. Now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears there is an end of line, to solve this in PHP use `rtrim(file_get_contents())` like so:

```
<a href="mailto:<?php echo rtrim(file_get_contents('tempmail'));?>"><?php echo rtrim(file_get_contents('tempmail'));?></a>
```

From the php manual:

> file_get_contents() is the preferred way to read the contents of a
>   file into a string. It will use memory mapping techniques if supported
>   by your OS to enhance performance.

On the bash side of things, it is echo that introduces a newline, so if you don't want it just use `echo -n`:

```
echo -n $TEMPMAIL"@myhost" > /home/user/html/tempmail
```